# Is angular Bundle size reduction possible if we move out packages (which could be moved) from "dependencies" key to "devDependencies?"

Tags: angular, performance, package.json, npm-package

My angular app's `package.json` file looks like this

[image: Image-01]

[image: Image-02]

[image: Image-03]

My Objective is: **to reduce the ultimate bundle size(s)**

My queries are:

1. If I move some packages from `dependencies` list to `devDependencies` list - will I have any reduction in bundle size?
2. If I can do so, how may I identify which are all the packages that can be in `devDependencies` and which are all the packages that shall be in `dependencies` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes doing this will reduce the bundle size, but be aware because devDependencies is used to store the dependencies you need during development phase only and the dependencies are those that your project really needs to be able to work in production.Do not change dependencies to devdependencies manually.

Comment: How can I identify the packages that can be moved to `devDependencies` from `dependencies` section?